# Difference among Emacs org-mode in GUI, gnome-terminal and Guake terminal?

Tags: emacs, terminal

I am new to Emacs. I watched a video about `org-mode` and trying to implement it while watching. However, I found it different while editing Emacs GUI, gnome-terminal and Guake terminal.

My laptop runs an Ubuntu 16.04.

I found that every key binding works exactly the same as in the video, however, when it comes to Guake terminal and Gnome-terminal, for some little key bindings, they are different. (I started Emacs using `emacs -nw`, and I have disabled the `Alt` key from associating with the menu bar and HUD.)

The one that is different is when I have a line like this :

```
** UNDO item1
```

Then I would like to insert a new line after it.

When pressing `Alt+Shift+Enter`,
in Emacs GUI, it comes with

```
** UNDO
```

while in gnome-terminal, it comes with

```
**
```

without the UNDO.

Then in Guake terminal, it just comes with nothing but a new line.

Could anyone tell me what makes the difference?

Is there any way that I can use Emacs in Guake terminal exactly the same as it is Emacs GUI?

Comment: I've never heard of Guake, but I presume this is simply a duplicate of https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/18000 and friends?  From your description, I would expect that if you type `C-h k` and then Alt+Shift+Enter, Emacs would describe the sequence it *actually received* differently in each of your three scenarios.

Comment: yes you are right. they actually received different commands. Thanks